# Postgres - gin index doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

it seems that my server won't use gin index.

1. I've created a new database with one table.
2. I've inserted one row as example.
3. I've loaded trigram extension and created gin index using trigrams
4. But when I check if the index works right I can see it doesn't
5. Any ideas?

**SQL:** http://pastebin.com/1yDQQA1Z

P.S. A day ago I've followed a tutorial about trigrams. Basically it was the same like my example above. The table had 2 columns, numeric(5, 0) and character varying (the one with gin trgm index). Query was with like operator using "%" and index was working (I could see Bitmap using in query explain), so I know, my server can use index (and its properly installed).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S.S I've tried to load extension first and then create table, or insert data and then create index... i've tried many combinations but without any luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't test on one row, it is meaningless.

Here's an excerpt of the documentation explaining why, in [Examining Index Usage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-examine.html):

> Use real data for experimentation. Using test data for setting up
>   indexes will tell you what indexes you need for the test data, but
>   that is all.
>
> It is especially fatal to use very small test data sets. While
>   selecting 1000 out of 100000 rows could be a candidate for an index,
>   selecting 1 out of 100 rows will hardly be, because the 100 rows
>   probably fit within a single disk page, and there is no plan that can
>   beat sequentially fetching 1 disk page.